# Question about notation - Missing vertical bar

Tags: real-analysis, notation

In Theorem 1 of the paper [*A Brief History of the Strong Szegö Limit Theorem*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-0348-0411-0_8), the author writes
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \lvert a_k \rvert+ \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\lvert k \rvert   a_k\rvert^2.
$$
Can someone explain why one $\lvert$ is missing? Is this a typo or a common thing to do?
He uses the same notation again at the end of page 2.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a typo. If you look at the referenced paper [15] in the article, as mentioned at the end of page 2 in relation to a result, there is a similar expression:
[image]

[image]

It is difficult to see, although, I believe the expression writes
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}|\varphi_k|
+ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} |k| |\varphi_k|^2,
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\|\varphi_k\|
+ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} |k| \|\varphi_k\|^2,
\end{align}
$$
respectively; where I assume the $\varphi_k$ corresponds to the $a_k$ in the initial paper.

Comment: It feels kind of weird that the author made such an obvious typo in the first theorem. So I wanted to ask if there might be some convention that I don't know about. I will accept your answer if no one has a better idea.

Comment: @HyyFly I agree, it is a little strange, and of course, that's not a problem. Hope the symbol search goes well :).